# Should I install Sharepoint 2010 on a separate OS instance?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, development-environment, environment

I will need a Sharepoint Server 2010 install for learning purposes.. I already have a Win 7 x64 os installation with vs2010 and I use it for my current development needs.
The question is ... would you recommend to install sharepoint onto an existing win 7 installation, create a separate OS instance (win7 or win 2008 r2?) for sharepoint development purposes or maybe create a VM for that?  I have 4GBs of ram and I wont be able to extend it.
What are your experiences with dev environments for sharepoint 2010? I remember that 2007 was a real resource hog - maybe there is a 'magical' switch that allows sharepoint 2010 related services to be turned off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you thought SharePoint 2007 is a resource hog, SharePoint 2010 is even worse. The full installation creates lots of Windows services and IIS application pools. Which makes it really hard to stop SharePoint since all those services start automatically.I agree with others that you should use the VM approach but I think you need Windows Server 2008 R2 to be able to create 64-bit VMs.

Here's a link to powershell scripts for stopping/starting SharePoint services: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emberger/archive/2009/11/16/stop-and-go-with-sharepoint-2010-on-your-workstation.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I personally always run it in a different instance - either a separate machine or a virtual machine. Sharepoint 2010 is massive, and changes your system with a magnitude not seen by any previous sharepoint version, in terms of databases, scheduled tasks, services...

Answer (score 0):

You should install your SharePoint 2010 in Server2008 R2 if you can ,since then you can do a complete install and use domain account.The installation in win7 is a standalone install and only use system account.It does not match what is in production...

Or if you can, virtualize your SharePoint environment.You need to give at least 4gb ram to SharePoint VM otherwise it is running like a dog.